# Dividing all possible rows within a given sub-data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations, division

My data looks like this:

```
set <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4)
density <- c(1,3,3,1,3,1,1,1,3,3,1,3)
counts <- c(100,2,4,76,33,12,44,13,54,36,65,1)
data <- data.frame(set,density,counts)
data$set <- as.factor(data$set)
data$density <- as.factor(data$density)
```

Within a given set there are two levels of densities "1" or "3". For a given set, I want to divide all possible combinations of counts of density "1" and density "3". I then want to print the original density associated with density "1", the ratio, and the set

For example, the result for the first few rows should look like:

```
 set counts ratio
  1   100    50  #100/2
  1   100    25  #100/4
  2   76     2.3 #76/33
  3   12     0.22 #12/54
  3   12     0.33 #12/36
  3   44     0.8148 #44/54
 ...
```

I thought I could achieve it by dplyr..but it seems a little too complicated for dplyr.

Comment: If you `inner_join` the `density==3` and `density==1` subsets together, it should then just be a simple division.

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt with `dplyr`. Are you open for `base` or `data.table` solutions?

Comment: @thelatemail I have never used inner_join before and I'm looking up some examples that show a similar example. If you have any in mind, can you please point them to me?

Comment: @Henrik I am going to try the inner_join dplyr as suggested by another user (although I;ve never used it before). I am open to data. table solutions..not sure what base is. But as long as I can convert it back to data.frame in the end it should be alright

Comment: @thelatemail So I did `inner_join(data$density=="1",data$density=="6", by = NULL)` and I get an error that says `no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "logical"`. Do I have to change object type?

Comment: `base` is one of the "base packages" (see e.g. your `sessionInfo()`) which ships with the standard R installation.

Comment: Aahh..alright. Yup, that should work too

Comment: @Biotechgeek - you need to subset the original object - `inner_join(data[data$density==1,],data[data$density==3,], by = "set")` I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the comments get you most of the way there. Here's a `dplyr` solution. With `left_join` each of the density1's get matched up with all density3's in the same set, providing output in line with your specification.

```
# Edited below to use dplyr syntax; my base syntax had a typo

library(dplyr)
data_combined <- data %>% filter(density == 1) %>%
   # Match each 1 w/ each 3 in the set
   left_join(data %>% filter(density == 3), by = "set") %>%  
   mutate(ratio = counts.x / counts.y) %>%
   select(set, counts.x, counts.y, ratio)

data_combined
#   set counts.x counts.y      ratio
#1    1      100        2 50.0000000
#2    1      100        4 25.0000000
#3    2       76       33  2.3030303
#4    3       12       54  0.2222222
#5    3       12       36  0.3333333
#6    3       44       54  0.8148148
#7    3       44       36  1.2222222
#8    3       13       54  0.2407407
#9    3       13       36  0.3611111
#10   4       65        1 65.0000000
```

Comment: Your code won't work if there is no `density` vector in the global workspace. You need `data[data$density==1,] ` and the same for the `==3` subset too.

Comment: Thank you, corrected to use the `dplyr` syntax with which I make fewer typos.